# cardboard sdk's head tracking auto rotates

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I'm using cardboard's sdk script for unity for auto rotate with head tracking but even if Im not moving the phone, the view keeps rotating to the right and it also rotates in the forward axis aswell. Is there any way to fix this or how to create a script that works properly and fixes the wrong tracking?

Comment: It is a known issue on the cardboard sdk: "The amount of drift depend on the specific hardware" [see this issue](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/338) or [this one](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/309)

Comment: okey but is there a way to manually do it and to it a bit more accurate? @Ludovic

Comment: I don't know, i never seen this issue on my projects. You should try to read about this issue on the Cardboard SDK github to know more about it.